# ionic 5 native barcode scanner - Unable to import

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

Hoping to get some help on this. I am trying to import Ionic’s native Barcode Scanner into my Ionic 5, Angular 9 app. I have capacitor installed and used the following method to install the barcode scanner:

```
npm install phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
npm install @ionic-native/barcode-scanner
ionic cap sync
```

I then setup the barcode scanner in a component as follows:

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';

constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) { }

this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
 console.log('Barcode data', barcodeData);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error', err);
});
```

This threw a null injector error. Seeing the forums it looked like you have to import the barcodescanner in app modules as a provider. I did this as follows in app.modules.ts:

```
import {BarcodeScanner} from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
.....
providers: [
    BarcodeScanner,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    FileTransfer, FileTransferObject,
    File,
    InAppBrowser,
    Keyboard,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    UpdateService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

The issue is I now get the following error:
Invalid provider for the NgModule ‘AppModule’ - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed

Any one else come across this issue before and the solution? I haven’t installed cordova just capacitor which I understand is all I need, is this correct?

Appreciate any help on this as I am at a dead end. Below ionic info + version of barcde scanner installed. Many thanks in advance.

```
@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.26.0",
@ionic-native/core": "^5.26.0

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.7
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.1.2
   @capacitor/core : 2.1.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v12.14.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : macOS Catalina
   Xcode  : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably import the BarcodeScanner from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx' instead of '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner' in your app.module.